# Meteor .meteor/local/bundler-cache/linker folder is 709MB

Tags: meteor

For some reason, my .meteor/local/bundler-cache/linker folder is 700+MB of .cache files. These files seem to continually grow over time. If I meteor reset and start over, my project goes from 100MB to 300MB immediately. Any thoughts on how figure out what is going wrong? How can I find out what is writing to bundler_cache folder?

```
webapp|master ⇒ du -sh .meteor/local/bundler-cache/linker
709M    .meteor/local/bundler-cache/linker

linker|master ⇒ du 4e66b88173386163ea6cd7a6ee945a12f3ab5920.cache
208 4e66b88173386163ea6cd7a6ee945a12f3ab5920.cache

bundler-cache|master ⇒ find linker -type f | wc -l
 619
```

Comment: It seems meteor never clear caches.... This is definently the problem which I encounter as well

Comment: Since your ticket has already been answered - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5818 - would you like to post and accept your own answer?

Comment: Meteor store cache date eternaly, I've been up to 3Gb of data in that file.
You can safely delete it without any problem.